# Unable to receive email in AWS SES using SNS and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to receive email in SES using SNS and a Lambda function.

I have verified example@gmail.com as an email address in SES and I have created a rule set with example@gmail.com as the recipient and an SNS topic as the action. The rule set is enabled.

The Lambda is subscribed to the SNS topic and when I send a test message in the AWS console on the topic, I can see in CloudWatch that the Lambda got the message.

However, when I send an email to example@gmail.com, the Lambda doesn't get the email.

Any ideas?

Below are some related code/config:

- SES verified email
  [image: SES verified email]
- Receipt rule action
  [image: Receipt rule action]
- SNS topic access policy

```json
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:my-account-id:EmailImagesStack-TopicBFC7AF6E-8ZD350QFNU12",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "my account id"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: To get the community to help you with this, please show your logic.

Comment: Not sure if there's that much logic to show, but I added some related stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Receive mail in SES require some prerequisites describes in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-setting-up.html).

> - Verify your **domain** with Amazon SES by publishing DNS records to prove that **you own** it.
> - Permit Amazon SES to receive email for your domain by **publishing an MX record**.
> - **Give** Amazon SES **permission** to access other AWS resources in order to execute receipt rule actions.

I guess you don't owning domain `gmail.com`, so SES can not receive mail for you from `example@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 0):

For Gmail, repeating email caused it to show as promotions email instead of primary email.

From left navigation bar, just click "All mail"
From center content, click "Promotions" tab beside "Primary" tab.

It will show all the emails received from AWS SNS.